# How to pass message to isolate and handle error

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I am trying to use dart isolate library to improve my application performance.

Look at following code:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:dbcrypt/dbcrypt.dart';

main() {

  var pwConPort = new ReceivePort();
  pwConPort.listen((data) {
      print(data);
      pwConPort.close();
  }, onError: (err) {
      print(err);
  });

  Isolate.spawn(generatePasswordConcurrency, pwConPort.sendPort);

}

void generatePasswordConcurrency(SendPort sendPort) {
    sendPort.send(_generateHashPassword('Passsowr1222!'));

}

String _generateHashPassword(String password) {
    var regex = new RegExp(r'^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$');
    if (!regex.hasMatch(password)) {
        throw new StateError('Errors');
    }
    return new DBCrypt().hashpw(password, new DBCrypt().gensalt());
}
```

Everything works fine but i can only pass a static password, or better to say, i don't know, how to pass something dynamically. Here you can see, password is hardcoded, but i want to pass a variable for example.

```dart
void generatePasswordConcurrency(SendPort sendPort) {
    sendPort.send(_generateHashPassword('Passsowr1222!'));

}
```

If the method _generateHashPassword will throw an error, how can I handling this error? I try to catch the error on listen method from ReceivePort

```dart
  pwConPort.listen((data) {
      print(data);
      pwConPort.close();
  }, onError: (err) {
      print(err);
  });
```

but still got unhandling exceptions message.

```dart
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51433
in ShutdownIsolate: Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Errors
#0      _generateHashPassword (file:///D:/Dart/samples/bin/isolate_error.dart:26:9)
#1      generatePasswordConcurrency (file:///D:/Dart/samples/bin/isolate_error.dart:19:40)
#2      _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:221)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:124)
```

Conclusion my question:

> How can I pass a variable to called method on isolate?
>   How can I handling error on isolate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all,

Isolate are not thread, they are independant process more like a `fork()` than a thread

[dartApi: Isolate](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3aisolate)

> Concurrent programming using isolates: 
>     independent workers that are similar to threads **but don't share memory**, communicating only via
>   messages.

So, you can't access to the same variable than your parent process. It's a choice made by the dart team, because it's a mechanism usable when you compile your dart code in js. So it need to be possible in JS

***How can I pass a variable to called method on isolate?***

To do this, you need to see `ReceivePort()` like a unidirectionnal way of communication, so to pass variable in two way, you need two.

So on you main process:

```dart
pwConPort.listen((data) {
      if (isolateSendPort == null && data is SendPort) {
        isolateSendPort = data; // Receive the communication object of the isolate
        isolateSendPort.send("Passsowr1222!");
      } else {
        print("Generated password: ${data}");
        pwConPort.close();
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("SendPortError: ${err}");
    });
  });
```

In you isolate entry point :

```dart
 sendPort.send(isolateConPort.sendPort);
    isolateConPort.listen((data) {
      // code ....
    });
```

**Note:** be careful of what message you send. message send between one process and another need to respect some rules

[DartApi: SendPort](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-isolate.SendPort)

> The content of ***message can be: primitive values (null, num, bool,
>   double, String), instances of SendPort, and lists and maps*** whose
>   elements are any of these. List and maps are also allowed to be
>   cyclic.

***How can I handling error on isolate?***

Isolate get one method to listen throw error send by the isolate : [addErrorListner](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-isolate.Isolate#id_addErrorListener)
That is a useful function.

**BUT !** this method is not implement in every plate-forme, so you need to do this in a others.

The way i chose is to send 2 SendPort in the entry point function :

- One for the communication
- One for the error.

So the spawn function looks like :

```dart
Isolate.spawn(generatePasswordConcurrency, [pwConPort.sendPort, errorPort.sendPort])
```

and the `generatePasswordConcurrency` :

```dart
void generatePasswordConcurrency(List<SendPort> commList) {
    var sendPort = commList[0];
    var errorPort = commList[1];
    var isolateConPort = new ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send(isolateConPort.sendPort);
    isolateConPort.listen((data) {
      try {
        sendPort.send(_generateHashPassword(data));
      } catch (e) {
        errorPort.send("error: ${e.toString()}");
      }
    });
}
```

Here the full code :

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:dbcrypt/dbcrypt.dart';

main() {

  var pwConPort = new ReceivePort();
  var errorPort = new ReceivePort();
  SendPort isolateSendPort = null;

  Isolate.spawn(generatePasswordConcurrency, [pwConPort.sendPort, errorPort.sendPort])
  .then((Isolate pcs) {
    errorPort.listen((err) {
      print("Error: ${err}");
      pwConPort.close();
      errorPort.close();
    });
    print(pcs);

    pwConPort.listen((data) {
      if (isolateSendPort == null && data is SendPort) {
        isolateSendPort = data;
        isolateSendPort.send("Passsowr1222!");
      } else {
        print("Generated password: ${data}");
        pwConPort.close();
        errorPort.close();
        //pcs.kill();
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("SendPortError: ${err}");
    });
  });
}

void generatePasswordConcurrency(List<SendPort> commList) {
    var sendPort = commList[0];
    var errorPort = commList[1];
    var isolateConPort = new ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send(isolateConPort.sendPort);
    isolateConPort.listen((data) {
      try {
        sendPort.send(_generateHashPassword(data));
      } catch (e) {
        errorPort.send("error: ${e.toString()}");
      }
    });
}

String _generateHashPassword(String password) {
  var regex = new RegExp(r'^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$');
  if (!regex.hasMatch(password)) {
    throw new StateError('Errors');
  }
  return new DBCrypt().hashpw(password, new DBCrypt().gensalt());
}
```

Comment: And what is c function?

Comment: It is not possible to use isolate on frontend right only backend?

Comment: It's possible, but it's maybe a bit more complicate

Comment: @zero_coding: Command line apps may use `Isolate.spawn()`. Web apps **can** spawn isolates but must use `Isolate.spawnUri()`.